# Comparison test integral convergence

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{x^x} \,\mathrm dx$$

How can I tell if this integral converges or not? I was thinking of using the comparison test, but I can't think of anything to compare it to. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x^x=e^{x\ln{x}},$ then for $x>e$
$$\frac{e^x}{x^x}=e^{x(1-\ln x)}=\dfrac{1}{e^{x(\ln x-1)}}<\dfrac{1}{e^{x}},$$

therefore,  $\displaystyle\int\limits_{e}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^x}{x^x} \,\mathrm dx$ converges. On $(0,\,e)$ integrand is bounded, because $x^x\underset{x\to{0^{+}}}{\to}{1},$ so $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^x}{x^x} \,\mathrm dx$ is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\frac{e^x}{x^x}=e^{x-x\log x}=_\infty o(\frac{1}{x^2})$$
and
$$\frac{e^x}{x^x}=e^{x-x\log x}\to_01$$
so the the given integral is convergent.

Comment: I was about to tell you that it is false in general that $f\sim g$ implies $h\circ f\sim h\circ g$... but you've edited, so +1.

Comment: @julien I'm lucky because even I often make mistakes, but I know that you'll correct me.

Comment: I hope it does not bother you...If it does, I won't ever do it again, promise. You rarely make "mistakes" though. Not more often than me, for sure.

Comment: @julien No on the contrary your comment is welcome :)

Comment: Everyone makes mishtakes...

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted to use the comparison test:

If $x \ge e^2$, then $\ln x \ge 2$, and so $1-\ln x \le -1$ which gives $e^{x(1-\ln x)} \le e^{-x}$.

Since $t \mapsto e^t$ is a bijection of $(-\infty, 2]$ onto $(0,e^2]$, we see that $M=\sup_{x\in (0,e^2]} e^{x(1-\ln x)} = \sup_{t \in (-\infty, 2]}e^{e^t (1-t)} < \infty$, and so we have $\frac{e^x}{x^x} \le M e^{e^2} e^{-x}$ for all $x >0$.